# Developing a react app on multiple machines

Tags: reactjs, git, workflow, collaboration

I set up a react app on my desktop for development using react-create. I am keeping track of changes using a git repository. I wanted to work on it from my laptop, so I cloned the repository but I can't spin the site up on my localhost (laptop). I tried to react-create on the laptop, but it won't run unless I rm the core files.

So my question is, how can I work on the same react app using multiple machines?

I think in any development shop, this would be one of the first skills you learn. But as a solo learner, I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome! Could you clarify "the core files"? Did you install dependencies for react-create? Did you install the project (npm / yarn install) after cloning from git?

Comment: I tried to react-create again, and it said that the yarn.lock and package.json files, and the src and public folders needed to be removed. I didn't install any dependencies.I didn't know about the install command. So if I clone my project, and it is in folder called myProject, I should try "react-install myProject" ? Thanks for answering, this is my first time posting.

Comment: It seems like installing all the dependencies was the only thing keeping my app from working. I got the app to work by following vieko's checklist.